# How can I get distinct values from two tables using union?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Using KQL how can I get distinct values from two tables?

I tried the following

```
let brandstorelensscandevicedata = scandevicedata
| distinct Brand
| where Brand != "null";
let brandresellapp = usertrackerdevicedata
| distinct Brand
| where Brand != "null";
brandstorelensscandevicedata
| union kind=inner brandresellapp
```

But it gives me duplicates when a brand exists in both tables

How can I get unique brands from both tables and avoid duplicates?

Comment: Matt, do you have a Brand called "null" or you just trying to get rid of nulls?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz long story about the null :), some legacy I have to deal with unfortunately they injected some strings that are "null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution
let scandevicedata = materialize(range i from 1 to 10 step 1 | extend Brand = iff(rand()<0.2, "null", strcat("Brand_", toint(rand(9)))), x1 = rand(), x2 = rand());
let usertrackerdevicedata = materialize(range i from 1 to 10 step 1 | extend Brand = iff(rand()<0.2, "null", strcat("Brand_", toint(rand(9)))), x1 = rand(), x3 = rand());
// Solution starts here
union scandevicedata, usertrackerdevicedata
| distinct Brand
| where Brand != "null"
```

| Brand |
| --- |
| Brand_6 |
| Brand_7 |
| Brand_2 |
| Brand_0 |
| Brand_5 |
| Brand_8 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA82QwWrDMBBE7wb/w8QnG0wcp6fS5lJy7qUfUBZpnYjKkpHWbSj5%20EqxKQT6AdVtVjPL2%20k6HEkIkcbJMk7sOJAY77Z49YKJgsAPkDMjejvnn7KwLIiKnOZPo1jn/AEjCQdD1nxzHcidGAZD8CN6iEe/QxSekriCL8JO4yW5dAqaYcgBXTfPu%202%20ReVma6s2%20YMiqaub7z0NxBsni/WxSa/FpU/5JZvE/lc0TwvkHDlIIPXB4Z%20xPtyxdh3e1nbTqtR5xJkDl8XsbqO7rtu/zyqLK7SJYpyShTdPvvKeFX9zWHl/ACAK6071AQAA)